# OpenSocial gadget-to-gadget communication via gadgets.rpc

Tags: rpc, opensocial

Could I have an example of communication between two OpenSocial gadgets using the [gadgets.rpc](http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Gadgets.rpc_%28v0.9%29) API?

I've searched for one, but the closest I can find is a deprecated example of gadget-to-*container* communication.

Comment: The rarity of examples may have something to do with the fact that the initial reference OpenSocial container has a bug that prevents gadget-to-gadget RPC from working - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHINDIG-1473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pubsub for gadget-to-gadget communication.

on a gadget, you subscribe for an event as follows:

```
gadgets.pubsub.subscribe("my_event_type",whenEventHappens);
function whenEventHappens(sender, message){
      alert(message.content);
}
```

on another gadget, you publish events as follows:

```
var message = {};
message["content"] = "hey,wassup?";
gadgets.pubsub.publish("my_event_type", message);
```